# I have a Dahon Mariner, can I replace 20x1.6" tyre with 20x1.79?

Tags: tire, replacement, size

I have a Dahon Mariner Bike. Can I replace a 20 x 1.6" back tyre with a 20 x 1.79" tyre as I can't get hold of a 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

The width of the tyre is like clothes sizes. What they state is not an exact fit. A brand's 1.79" might measure 1.9" wide and a different brand's 1.79" might measure 1.65".

You need to have a look at your current setup, check how much extra space you have and decide whether the new tyre will fit. Again, if you think it might be a tight fit, having a wider than stated tyre (virtual 17.9" measuring 1.9") may not work.

Having mudgards also affects what width tyre you can use.

So I suggest you look at how much room you have to increase tyre size, and take it from there.